# Extract phone's exact location using GPS and change device settings according to it

Tags: android, gps, android-gps, location-based-service

Im creating an app that'll use GPS to determine user's exact location. User can manually add locations when he/she is actually on that location (something like add here),and user can add as many entries he want.
Then when user goes back to any of those predefined locations,app should automatically detect the location and execute the task user asked to do (in here,something like put phone into silent/vibrate only or normal mode).
how can I do that?
Please help.

Comment: This feature is called Geofencing. https://developer.android.com/training/location/geofencing.html

Answer (score 0):

The first comment you received is along the right track for sure with Geofencing. I would check out this free course from Udacity.com...[Google Location Services](https://www.udacity.com/course/google-location-services-on-android--ud876-1). The course will walk you through how to do almost exactly what you want. You will just need to tweak the code and add whatever else you want to your app.

I hope this helps! If you have any questions just comment!